# How define Sticky position for elements on WordPress website

Tags: css, wordpress

In my WordPress website, I want to define a sticky position for three elements. I tried two ways but didn't work.
First - I used a plugin 'Sticky Menu (or Anything!)', but I couldn't sticky more than one element.
Second - I added CSS code in Additional CSS part, but It didn't work.
My CSS code is here:

```
position: sticky;
top: 120px;
z-index: 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, the theme elements are nested so parent elements may override your styles, you need to illustrate the use-case in more details, also you may need to consider using !important to override any CSS rules that are inherited to children elements.

```
position: sticky !important;
top: 120px !important;
z-index: 1000 !important;
```

You may also consider reading more about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)